# How to link two zones in OpenX

Tags: banner, openx, zone

we'd like to have OpenX manage some ad banner type that consists of a leaderboard and a medium rectangle banner (an example would be here in the top right corner: https://www.sevenonemedia.de/image_gallery/12/07/37/1207370.jpg). From my understanding the leaderboard and the medium rectangle are configured as two different zones. So how do I link these two zones in OpenX so that both banners always show the same campaign?

Best Regards,
sparafucile

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear so it's possible that i misunderstood, if you want to assign two different zone to a campaign you need to follow this steps:
1. Create/Select an Advertiser and be sure that the Miscellaneous property "Display only one banner from this advertiser on a web page" is NOT CHECKED !
2. Create/Select the campaign and add/link the desired zones, from the Linked Zones tab on the campaign page.
3. Create the banner for the campaign.

It should work !